# Помогите с ошибками скрипта node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я создал все файлы [из урока](https://habrahabr.ru/post/127525/) и написал в консоли `node server.js`.

Выходит вот что:

```
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1236:14)
    at listen (net.js:1272:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1368:5)
    at Server.listen.Server.attach (/Users/doge/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:216:9)
    at new Server (/Users/doge/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:50:17)
    at Function.Server (/Users/doge/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:38:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/doge/Desktop/server.js:2:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
```

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы всё заработало?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Вопросы-ссылки, предлагающие посмотреть проблемный код в стороннем источнике, недопустимы на StackOverflow на русском.

Answer (score 2):

Тут явно прописана ошибка: `EADDRINUSE`
("**E**rror: **ADDR**ess **IN** **USE**", "Ошибка: адрес уже занят").

Для того, чтобы завести можно сменить порт (`8080`) на другой: например, `8081`.

Comment: спасибо вам за ответ добрый вы человек!

Comment: @FRESTAR "Спасибо" у нас принято высказывать нажатием на стрелочку вверх у ответа (т. н. "голос за") и обозначением галочкой, если этот ответ привёл к решению.

Comment: @D-side По-моему, после вашего совета он не на ту стрелку тыкнул :D

Answer (score 0):

Это ошибка того, что Вы уже запустили `node.js` на этом порту или порт занятый. Если `node.js` уже запущенный на этом порту, просто убейте процес командой `sudo fuser -vk 8080/tcp`. Если же порт занятый, например, может быть запущенный `apache`, то запустите `node.js` на другом порту, например на `8888`.